# Get value from Encoded Url

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

I am trying to get a value from a Encoded URL in C#. So for example, I am trying to get "customerID" from:

```
  http://<DOMAIN>/default.aspx%3FcustomerID%3D12345%26reference%3D2222
```

I tried the following:

```
  string customerID = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["customerID"]);
```

But it comes back NULL. What is the proper way to get this value??

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Decode the url first, it is not finding the querystring "customerID".

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = " http://DOMAIN/default.aspx%3FcustomerID%3D12345%26reference%3D2222";

var url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str);
var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri(url).Query);
var id = parameters["customerID"];
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Was trying to think of the way to do this and was unaware of ParseQueryString functionality. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your application should be encoding the ? and = signs.  The Request variables are setup by iis usually before the information is handed off to the application handling the request.  You need to send the should encode values but not the entire url.  If your url looked like, 
?customerID=1234 I imagine it would work, the problem is not with your code but with how the url is being constructed.

Comment: OP is trying to pull values from an **already** encoded URL - not sure your answer is what their looking for...

Comment: Thanks, but my URL is already encoded and was looking to parse the values. It has to be encoded so can't switch to unencoded.